# UIWebview 上のフォームからのPOST情報取得 (画像, multipart/form-data)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

初投稿です。 よろしくお願いいたします。

サーバに以下の様な PHP ファイルを置き `UIWebView` に読み込ませています。

```
<form action="native://test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png" name="files" name="photo">
<input type="text" name="name">
...
</form>
```

Swiftで、`shouldStartLoadWithRequest` メソッドで

```
var data:NSData? = request.HTTPBody
```

とすると `data` は `nil` になります。

```
<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png" name="files" name="photo">
```

を消すと `data` は `nil` ではなく正しく取得できます。

やりたいことは Form から送った画像を SQLite にも保存したいのです。
別の方法でも結構です、どうかご教授願います。

Answer (score 2):

送信されるデータ量が多い場合は、`HTTPBody`ではなく`HTTPBodyStream`にデータがセットされるようです。

`HTTPBodyStream`から`NSMutableData`に全データを読み込むサンプルコードです。

```
if let stream = request.HTTPBodyStream {
  stream.open()
  var data:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
  while stream.hasBytesAvailable {
    var buffer = [UInt8](count: 512, repeatedValue: 0)
    let len:Int = stream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
    data.appendBytes(buffer, length: len)
  }
}
```

Comment: 動作しましたが画像ファイルの区切りがわかりません。
そのため、サンプルではバッファーサイズを512byteにしていますが、jQueryにて画像サイズを取得しそれを
  <input type="hidden">
を使ってswiftで取得しようと思いますが、もっと良い方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: 区切りについては新しく質問を投稿したほうが良いと思います。